# Transform an hourly dataframe into a monthly totalled dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a Pandas dataframe containing hourly precipitation data (tp) between 2013 and 2020, the dataframe is called df:

```
                      tp
time                    
2013-01-01 00:00:00  0.1
2013-01-01 01:00:00  0.1
2013-01-01 02:00:00  0.1
2013-01-01 03:00:00  0.0
2013-01-01 04:00:00  0.2
                 ...
2020-12-31 19:00:00  0.2
2020-12-31 20:00:00  0.1
2020-12-31 21:00:00  0.0
2020-12-31 22:00:00  0.1
2020-12-31 23:00:00  0.0
```

I'm trying to convert this hourly dataset into monthly totals for each year, I then want to take an average of the monthly summed rainfall so that I end up with a data frame with 12 rows for each month, showing the average summed rainfall over the whole period.

I've tried the resample function:

```
df.resample('M').mean()
```

However, this outputs the following and is not what I'm looking to achieve:

```
                 tp1
time                
2013-01-31  0.121634
2013-02-28  0.318097
2013-03-31  0.356973
2013-04-30  0.518160
2013-05-31  0.055290
             ...
2020-09-30  0.132713
2020-10-31  0.070817
2020-11-30  0.060525
2020-12-31  0.040002
2021-01-31  0.000000

[97 rows x 1 columns]
```

While it's converting the hourly data to monthly, I want to show an average of the rainfall across the years.

e.g.

January Column = Average of January rainfall between 2013 and 2020.

Comment: Can you take a look to the interesting comment of @mozway below my answer please?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your index is a `DatetimeIndex`, you can use:

```
out = df.groupby(df.index.month).mean()
print(out)

# Output
           tp1
time          
1     0.498262
2     0.502057
3     0.502644
4     0.496880
5     0.499100
6     0.497931
7     0.504981
8     0.497841
9     0.499646
10    0.499804
11    0.506938
12    0.501172
```

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(2022)
dti = pd.date_range('2013-01-31', '2021-01-31', freq='H', name='time')
df = pd.DataFrame({'tp1': np.random.random(len(dti))}, index=dti)
print(df)

# Output
                          tp1
time                         
2013-01-31 00:00:00  0.009359
2013-01-31 01:00:00  0.499058
2013-01-31 02:00:00  0.113384
2013-01-31 03:00:00  0.049974
2013-01-31 04:00:00  0.685408
...                       ...
2021-01-30 20:00:00  0.021295
2021-01-30 21:00:00  0.275759
2021-01-30 22:00:00  0.367263
2021-01-30 23:00:00  0.777680
2021-01-31 00:00:00  0.021225

[70129 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: You have to be careful with means of means, here you calculate the mean per month overall, which is not strictly identical to the mean of the monthly averages (mean of means ≠ mean of all if the subsizes are different). But OP isn't so clear on this point… (the clue a mean or mean might be wanted is "*… monthly totals for each year, I **then** want to take an average of the monthly...*")

Comment: @mozway. Do you mean (lol) it should be `df.resample('M').mean().groupby(lambda x: x.month).mean()`?

Comment: I guess, something like that, yes